# How do I fill NaN values with different random numbers on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, nan

I want to replace the missing values from a column with people's ages (which also contains numerical values, not only NaN values) but everything I've tried so far either doesn't work how I want it to or it doesn't work at all.

I wish to apply a random variable generator which follows a normal distribution using the mean and standard deviation obtained with that column.

I have tried the following:

- Replacing with numpy, replaces NaN values but with the **same number** for all of them

  ```
  df_travel['Age'] = df_travel['Age'].replace(np.nan, round(rd.normalvariate(age_mean, age_std),0))
  ```
- Fillna with pandas, also replaces NaN values but with the **same number** for all of them

  ```
  df_travel['Age'] = df_travel['Age'].fillna(round(rd.normalvariate(age_mean, age_std),0))
  ```
- Applying a function on the dataframe with pandas, replaces NaN values but **also changes all existing numerical values** (I only wish to fill the NaN values)

  ```
  df_travel['Age'] = df_travel['Age'].where(df_travel['Age'].isnull() == True).apply(lambda v: round(rd.normalvariate(age_mean, age_std),0))
  ```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) can accept a Series, so generate a random array of size `len(df_travel)`:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
mu = df_travel['Age'].mean()
sd = df_travel['Age'].std()

filler = pd.Series(rng.normal(loc=mu, scale=sd, size=len(df_travel)))
df_travel['Age'] = df_travel['Age'].fillna(filler)
```

Comment: Trying your method did help as it replaced NaN values with different numbers. However, this normal distribution causes the ages to be messed up:
`41.000000
     49.000000
     37.000000
     33.000000
     -0.535669
     32.000000
     59.000000
     30.000000
     38.000000
    36.000000
    35.000000
     0.041326
    31.000000
    34.000000
    28.000000
    29.000000
    32.000000
    22.000000
    53.000000
     1.042513`

Comment: I forgot to specify the mean and std of the distribution. Should be scaled correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with it the following way:

```py
# compute mean and std of `Age`
age_mean = df['Age'].mean()
age_std = df['Age'].std()

# number of NaN in `Age` column
num_na = df['Age'].isna().sum()

# generate `num_na` samples from N(age_mean, age_std**2) distribution
rand_vals = age_mean + age_std * np.random.randn(num_na)

# replace missing values with `rand_vals`
df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = rand_vals
```